# Extract multiple data from a single field

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to find a solution to deal with a single excel field which contain a couple of information. I will show you an example of what could contain those fields :

```
Field A1 : Coral Helm 7.154€ 21-22.12.13 

Field A2 : Wall of Spear 5€8-15.10.11

Field A3 : Clockwork Avian TBD 12-15.12.12

Field A4 : FellwarStone4-14-8.12.13

Field A5 : YotianSoldierTBD15-8-13
```

So to explain a little bit, basically this is the price of a card, with a range of date like 21-22.12.13 mean from 21.12.13 to 22.12.13. 
As you can see sometimes there are no space between word so i can't simply use the LEFT(), MID(), RIGHT() function.

I've search on the net to check if it was possible by using only excel formula but it seems it's way better to use VBA to deal with that kind of problems.
If anybody have an idea about how to deal with that it could be nice.

Comment: 1st Suggestion: Locate TBD or € in the cell and break that into 2 strings... and you can go from there...

Comment: What do you want as an ouput? your question is not clear, can you just elaborate a little?

Comment: I need to extract the 3 informations on a excel Cell : Description / Price / Date

Comment: In the case of "FellwarStone4-14-8.12.13", where is the price? The only thing I see in the middle is "4-".  Additionally, the range "14-8" doesn't make sense unless it's the 14th of the previous month. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) via the RegExp object, which you can include into your VBA project by going into the VBA IDE, clicking Tools ---> References... and checking the box next to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

The following pattern can match and split each of the items you listed except for "FellwarStone4-14-8.12.13":

```
"^([\w\s]+?(?=\s*TBD|\s*[0-9.]+€))\s*(TBD|[0-9.]+€)(.+)$"
```

Here is an example of how to use the RegExp object:

```
Public Sub SplitCell(cellvalue As String)
    Dim oRegExp As New RegExp
    Dim oMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim oMatch As Match
    Dim submatches() As String
    With oRegExp
        .Pattern = "^([\w\s]+?(?=\s*TBD|\s*[0-9.]+€))\s*(TBD|[0-9.]+€)\s*(.+)$"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Multiline = False
        Set oMatches = .Execute(cellvalue)
    End With
    If oMatches.Count <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Description: """ & oMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0) & """"
        MsgBox "Price: """ & oMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(1) & """"
        MsgBox "Date: """ & oMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(2) & """"
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not split cell value! It did not match the pattern."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just one question what happens if there is a number in the card name ?

Comment: @Sindar it works unless that number is squished right up against the price.  Then there would be no way to tell, for a human or a computer, without already knowing what the price should be.  For example, if there is a space in between, `China Vase3 4.34€12-15.12.12` would work just fine, but for `China Vase34.34€12-15.12.12`, the regular expression would match "34.34".  There is no way to know that the 3 isn't part of the price.